# Imagine Extension for Yii 2

Tags: php, image, yii2

With Yii framework 2.0 I want to use Imagine Extension for Yii 2. Following the documentation I have first run the following command line.

```
php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-imagine "*"
```

After running the command line above, I could see that the imagine package came in the vendor directory. In my views/site/index.php I included the following code snippet.

```
use yii\imagine\Image;

// generate a thumbnail image
Image::thumbnail('@webroot/img/test-image.jpg', 120, 120)
->save(Yii::getAlias('@runtime/thumb-test-image.jpg'), ['quality' => 50]);
```

The following is the result:

```
�PNG  IHDRxx9d6�  pHYs���+ IDATx���y�eW}��9w�o�o��ZJ��6��1`޺c��D�n�����L�8㈞G��c{�����r�ƀ$���R{UVV��[�{w?g�x�/�ʪJUI ;������=��l�������#.\�����Bl'��� @�ul� IL�@)����-�"MS<�C���+����Z��븫0�R��������Ã>���?����q�|�;ߡ�n�c�v������a Dg4'IJ��W�`���Įr��a}�V�^)�վ�~���l6{�|
```

There is no image shown. I don't know what I missed, the image path is correct. Does anyone know how to solve it? thanks

Comment: Save that binary string in to the file with valid extension

Comment: Can you explain me a bit more how to save that binary string in to the file with the valid extension? I think it is now saved with the name '@runtime/thumb-test-image.jpg' with the save() method.

Comment: How do you view the image? If you want to display it in a browser you'd need to send appropiate headers.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Image::thumbnail(Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/img/test-image.jpg', 120, 120)->save(Yii::getAlias('@runtime').'/thumb-test-image.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

after install yii2-imagine package to create thumbnail image by composer

php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-imagine

you need to full path to save uploaded image and thumbnail image so we are using full path like Yii::$app->basePath."/web/img/testimg.jpg".

you will need to add at top in siteController.php

Add syntax : use yii\imagine\Image;

then Try this

```
Image::thumbnail(Yii::$app->basePath."/web/img/testimg.jpg"., 120, 120)->save(Yii::$app->basePath."/web/img/thumb_testimg.jpg", ['quality' => 80]);
```

Comment: This  might be a valid answer, but it would be a better answer if you explained what your code is doing (you can [edit] your answer).

Answer (score 0):

This the right way to generate thumb and respect ratio:

```
use Imagine\Image\Box;
use yii\imagine\Image;

Image::getImagine()
                ->open($file)
                ->thumbnail(new Box($height, $width))
                ->save($file);
```